# Sync two source directories to two different destination directories using rsync

Tags: rsync

Is it possible to sync two source directories (say /var/a and /flash/b) to /var/a and /flash/b in the remote system using a single rsync command? Please advice

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on [SU], I voted to migrate it.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use `&&` or `;`?

*Explanation:*

`rsync src1 dst1 && rsync src2 dst2` will do second sync only if first one is done successfully.
`rsync src1 dst1; rsync src2 dst2` will try to do both syncs.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the command synopsis you see that rsync is made to copy one source to one destination: `rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]`. You could try some tricks with bind mounts or whatever, but in the end it will probably be the easiest if you ran rsync multiple times, or maybe write a simple shell script that invokes rsync multiple times.